# Javascript: Attributes on Element Request

Tags: javascript, rendering

If I get an element with `document.getElementById()`,

does javascript pull **all the attributes** of the element after I assigned to the variable `object`, or just when I request it by example: `object.id`?

```
var object = document.getElementById("object");

object.id;
object.value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really "pull" anything. The browser gives the JavaScript interpreter a reference to an object that, in ways peculiar to each browser, essentially **is** the DOM element. Accessing properties on DOM elements is pretty cheap, though **modifying** properties can have significant side-effects (which is usually why you'd want to modify a property from JavaScript, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Neither. The variable `object` is just a reference to an already existing object.

Answer (score 2):

`object` is a reference to the object itself. It does not pull/copy any values.

You can even try that by modifying a referenced object (example works here on SO):

```
> var object = document.getElementById("hlogo")
> object.id
"hlogo"
> document.getElementById("hlogo").id = "foobar"
"foobar"
> document.getElementById("hlogo").id
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
> object.id
"foobar"
```